# FullCalendar change cell color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want the cell color to change temporarily when users mouseover a day's cell in FullCalendar. The closest I've been able to come is eventMouseover, which only changes color if the cell is clicked (I am looking for hover or mouseover, not click). Without an object like a div, span or td, I find it difficult to apply an "onmouseover" command. Does this make sense? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did it a couple of weeks back. Just use css :hover. No JavaScript or magic needed :).

Comment: Thank you, Floyd. Where specifically did you employ CSS hover?

Comment: In fullcalendar.css file- lookin .fc-day .fc-widget-content.

Comment: Don't have a section called ".fc-day .fc-widget-content" in that CSS file. I guess I can create it myself. What version of FC are you using? Mine is 1.4.11 from 2011. I suspect that I should upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

```
.fc-day:hover{background:lightblue;cursor: pointer;}
```

Try this in fullcalendar.min.css or fullcalendar.css

Comment: To color events on hover`.fc-content:hover{background:lightblue;cursor: pointer;}`

Answer (score 1):

I've had success by simply doing this:

```
 .fc-content td:hover{background: #adf4fa;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Work like a charm:

```
.fc-list-item:hover td{
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I overwrited the calendar css this way, using less:

```
.fc-event:hover{
  border-color: @age-color-blue-dark;
  .fc-content{
    color:  @age-color-blue-dark;
  }
}
```

the compiled less css:

```
.fc-event:hover {
  border-color: #1c7d87;
}
.fc-event:hover .fc-content {
  color: #1c7d87;
}
```